# c# Automatically adding a new button if a new data is inserted into mysql

Tags: c#, mysql, c#-4.0, datagridview, c#-3.0

using dataGridView

How will a new button be automatically be added if a new data is inserted into the database table?

Say, I have a table named item_tbl. The item_tbl has a columns id, type, and description.

If I insert a new data where id = 001, type = "bread", and description = "sample bread". A button should automatically be created and will be inserted into the "item tab".

Else If I insert a new data where id = 002, type = "drinks", and description = "sample drinks". A button should automatically be created and will be inserted into the "drinks tab".

[image]

Comment: You don't know how to add the button or you don't know how to subscribe to some kind of event when the data is added? Also, this is winforms, right?

Comment: I dont know both @Sweeper

Comment: I don't see anywhere how this involves a DataGridView.

Answer (score 0):

Just write the new button code after the successfully insertion of record in the database. 
you can see it from your form designer code how to create new button.

Answer (score 0):

To create a button, simply declare a button object like you normally would:

```
Button myButton = new Button ();
```

And set the properties of the button e.g. Location, width & height

```
myButton.Text = "Sample Button";
myButton.Location = new Point (30, 30);
myButton.Size = new Size (100, 60);
```

The above numbers are just examples, you can change them however you want.

Then you gonna need to add the button to your form. It seems like that your button is in a container. Let's assume that the name of the container is "`container1`". In your form class, add the button to the container:

```
container1.Controls.Add (myButton);
```

And that's it! Isn't it simple?

Comment: Yes it creates new button but how to get the values from mysql table item_tbl and make it as a button. Please any help would be appreciated